Postgres connection not working with nextjs and drizzle
I followed the official documentation from Next or Drizzle but I can't configure next + drizzle + postgres..
I got this error:
VercelPostgresError: VercelPostgresError - 'missing_connection_string': You did not supply a 'connectionString' and no 'POSTGRES_URL' env var was found.

My .env and .env.development.local are set and similar with a POSTGRES_URL value. And here is my drizzle config file:
export default defineConfig({
  schema: "./db/schema.ts",
  out: "./drizzle",
  dialect: "postgresql",
  dbCredentials: {
    connectionString: process.env.POSTGRES_URL,
    url: process.env.POSTGRES_URL!,
  },
});

I also have the index.ts file
export const db = drizzle(sql);

And a envConfig.ts
import { loadEnvConfig } from "@next/env";
const projectDir = process.cwd();
loadEnvConfig(projectDir);

Thanks


Do not use images for textual data, copy and paste as text into question text. 2) The error is telling you that the env variable POSTGRES_URL is not set(exported) in the environment you are running this. You need to solve that problem first.


Console.log  process.env and see if your POSTGRES_URL is there. I'm not sure what the envConfig.ts does, but having your env vars inside of a .env file is enough for process.env to have access to the value
